# tinymce code editor over bootstrap modal is not editable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I have a strange problem that the code editor is not editable when displayed over bootstrap modal. Here is a code example.

https://jsfiddle.net/sogrbilja/4s9cyetk/14/

```
<div class="modal fade" id="_bodyModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Why I cannot edit html?</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea data*id="0" id="bodyText" ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="acceptChanges()">Primeni izmene</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" onclick="editEmailBody();">click here to invoke modal first</button>

    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#bodyText',
      height: 300,
      plugins: 'code',
      menubar: 'view'
    });
    
const _bodyModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('_bodyModal'), {
      keyboard: false
    });
    
    
function editEmailBody() {
    tinymce.get('bodyText').setContent("next click on View/Source code to invoke code editor and there try to change something, it is not possible, but i don know why");
    _bodyModal.show();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap will block all attempts to move focus to another modal dialog. So as noted in the [TinyMCE documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/bootstrap/#usingtinymceinabootstrapdialog) you need to prevent Bootstrap trapping the focus within the Bootstrap dialog. As it appears you're using Bootstrap 5, that means you'd need to add the following:

```js
// Prevent Bootstrap dialog from blocking focusin
document.addEventListener('focusin', (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest(".tox-tinymce-aux, .moxman-window, .tam-assetmanager-root") !== null) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
```

Here's an updated fiddle using the above and showing it working: https://jsfiddle.net/92dfrh5z/

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't search enough :)

Comment: Had a workaround very much like this for Bootstrap 4 which no longer works. Thanks for the BS5-compatible update!